# Can I use “do/did” to emphasize the verb “be” in passive clauses like “did be fixed”?

Tags: passive-voice, auxiliary-verbs, do-support

So, can I use something like this:

> This issue **did be** fixed.

instead of this:

> This issue **was** fixed.

?

Comment: In U.S. English, you would be more likely to say, "This issue did get fixed," if you insisted on using passive voice. But you'd get equally strong emphasis using active voice if you said "I did fix this issue."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Although *did* can be used for emphasis with many verbs, there are a few where it is not. For example, idiomatic uses include

- I did do that (even though you think I forgot).
- I did have it (but I've since lost it).
- I did go there (and I even bought a souvenir).

But not

- *I did can...
- *I did be...
- *I did will...

For all of these you need to use the regular past tense *could, was, would,* and simply verbally emphasise with a stress.

- I **could** play the piano (before I developed arthritis).
- I **was** injured (and I've now recovered).
- I **would** help you (but I have to wash my hair).

As a general rule, modal verbs — *can, could, may, might, will, would, must, shall, should* — can't use *did* for emphasis, and you simply have to stress the word itself. *Be* isn't really a modal verb, but is one of the verbs which can't use *did; ought [to]* is often listed as modal and there are dialects of English where *did* **can** be used.